# xpage Modal Dialog and sessionScopes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, xpages, session-scope

I have a repeat controller, with repeating buttons and clicking on a button opens up a dialog, and should show the correct document (combination of bootstrap).

Im setting a session scope variable on the click to set the doc ID, then the custom control within the modal has the documentID set from the session scope variable, however it doesn't seem to be working.

I think its because the modal is opening before the session scope variable is set.... Any ideas? Code below, thanks

```
    <xp:button value="Open File" id="button6"
                            styleClass="btn btn-info btn-block btn-tall">
                            <xp:this.attrs>

                                <xp:attr name="data-toggle"
                                    value="modal">
                                </xp:attr>
                                <xp:attr name="data-target"
                                    value="#Modal2">
                                </xp:attr>
                            </xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                refreshId="ccModalFileDetails">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.uploadedFileID = rowData.getUniversalID();
print ("HELLO: " + sessionScope.uploadedFileID)}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Comment: Please include the code for the datasource and also clarify if there are any other datasources on the page. It could be to do with `ignoreRequestParams`, but the code supplied can't confirm that.

Comment: Hi Paul, the other data source, the *parent* document. The repeat control is showing all the children (Parent document shown in the left column, the repeat control with children in a right column - so everything is displayed on one page)
The datasource code for the document which should show in the modal is:

<xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument var="document2" formName="frmUploadedFile"
   action="openDocument">
   <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("HERE:" + sessionScope.uploadedFileID);
sessionScope.uploadedFileID}]]></xp:this.documentId>
  </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>

Comment: Infact, looking a bit closer, it appears that the modal is trying to open the data from the parent document?

Comment: Where is the dataSource for the model bound?  The custom Control itself?  or the XPage that's holding it?

Comment: The custom control, however its now all set on one page, with no modal for testing ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure for your second dataSource ignoreRequestParams should be true and NOT false.

What that does is it tells your dataSource to NOT look at the URL for information on the binding.  So you definitely do want that second dataSource to ignore the url parameters. This is almost certainly why it's bringing in information from the parent.

Comment: Cheers David, as mentioned, working with all elements on one page, so now I'll try and replicate it via the modals. Life saver as always!

Comment: I'm an idiot! Checking back on my old code, everything was set correctly except.....



I had the modal contents all within the panel I was doing a partial refresh on, so it was loading the modal for a split second, then refreshing it, causing it to disappear!

Moving the panel I was refreshing within the modal has everything working.... I can't even blame Monday/Friday syndrome.... Thanks all for the help :-)